# Grouping and looping in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to do a sum on the columns MTH1 MTH2 etc but for the parameters I pass it will produce six rows of information for the same account code which is correct and what it should produce my question is how do I only return one of data but with all the sum of the six rows this is what I have so far for my stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sumbalances] 
    @AccountRef VARCHAR(500),
    @SortOrder INT,
    @CATEGORY INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT        
        NOMINAL_LEDGER.ACCOUNT_REF, NOMINAL_LEDGER.NAME, 
        NOMINAL_LEDGER.ACCOUNT_TYPE, NOMINAL_LEDGER.BALANCE, 
        NOMINAL_LEDGER.QUICK_RATIO, NOMINAL_LEDGER.SOFA_ID, 
        NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH1, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH2, 
        NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH3, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH4, 
        NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH5, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH6, 
        NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH7, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH8, 
        NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH9, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH10, 
        NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH11, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR_MTH12, 
        NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR2_MTH1, NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR2_MTH2, 
        NOMINAL_LEDGER.PRIOR_YR2_MTH3, 
    FROM            
        CATEGORY 
    LEFT JOIN
        NOMINAL_LEDGER ON CATEGORY.CompanyID = NOMINAL_LEDGER.CompanyID
    WHERE 
        ACCOUNT_REF = @AccountRef 
        AND SORT_ORDER = @SortOrder 
        AND CATEGORY = @CATEGORY
END
```

I presume that I would need some kind of loop to save the sum off all the MTH1's or would it not need to be as complicated as that.

Below is example of the data.

[image]

So for example if it was the Mth 1 it would add

```
40000.00
44000.00
```

And returns that total in the MTH 1 column but only one row for all of them being summed up if that make since.

**Edit 2**

Please see my sql fiddle here I am having some trouble linking the category table if someone could help be great. that is not the main issue of the above though so you guys can see the data

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6c902/1

Comment: please show the sample data from your base table

Comment: jump to `sqlfiddle.com` or `rextester.com`

Comment: I already have in the screen shot ? but will do a fiddle now

Comment: that is the expected result or source data ?

Comment: This is the source data.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu please see the above sql fiddle in my question

Comment: I think the better answer here might be to fix your table design. Having separate columns for different months, and years, is  ormally a bad idea; really you should be following Normal Form. Is fixing your table design an option?

Comment: @Larnu this is sage software i cannot change it

Comment: Would you please apply proper punctuation your questions and comments are very hard to read periods and commas are missing so are most capitals

Answer (score 1):

You seem to simply want a `GROUP BY`.  But you can also simplify the query in other ways:

```
select nl.ACCOUNT_REF, 
    sum(nl.PRIOR_YR_MTH1) as PRIOR_YR_MTH1,
    sum(nl.PRIOR_YR_MTH2) as PRIOR_YR_MTH2,
    . . .  - fill in the rest of the months
from NOMINAL_LEDGER nl join         
     CATEGORY c
     on c.CompanyID = nl.CompanyID
where nl.ACCOUNT_REF = @AccountRef and
      nl.SORT_ORDER = @SortOrder and
      c.CATEGORY = @CATEGORY
group by nl.ACCOUNT_REF;
```

Notes:

- The `WHERE` clause (presumably) undoes the `LEFT JOIN`, turning it into an `INNER JOIN`.  So use the proper `JOIN`.
- Table aliases make the query easer to write and to read.
- You seem to want one row per account, so the query aggregates by account and leaves out the other non-aggregated columns.